# Defining and using a cursor

Tags: mysql, cursor

I'm trying to make a MySQL stored procedure and I need to know how to use a cursor.

What is a cursor and can someone supply a trivial example?

Comment: can you fill us in on what you're trying to accomplish? Odds are pretty good that it can be done without resorting to a cursor at all.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

Comment: I am sure there is a ton of documentation out there on cursors.  I saw an interesting flow chart once about cursors.  It almost always pointed you towards not needing them.  Can you post your business problem and we can take a crack at it from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the MySQL docs about cursors: [Cursor Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html)

Essentially, you give a cursor an SQL statement and you can access the rows returned with SQL kind of like an iterator in any conventional programming language. Word of warning though, cursors are known to be extremely slow, so avoid their usage if you can.